# How can I properly add a subdivision surface to the side of a model? Eevee Blender 2.82a

Tags: subdivision-surface

I am working on a Star Destroyer model. I am at the point where I want to add textures. I want to add a subdivision surface modifier to the side of the ship only. I went into edit mode, selected the side (it has a mirror modifier), unwrapped it, added a texture and compiled some nodes together. I added the subdivision modifier. Firstly, this modifier is affecting the entire ship and not only the selected side. Secondly, I am not seeing the modifier's effect on the sides. I am including an image of my result and one of what I want to achieve. I tried with the discombobulator instead but it isn't working so I am assuming that my side isn't made up of quads. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could try going into edit mode, selecting the side of the ship, and in the right-click menu select subdivide

Comment: Thanks mate, just tried that and no effect whatsoever.